# cannot run test.php on localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost

So I installed php5 and apache2 on my local Debian system and want to run my test.  I have a test.php in /var/www  that has this in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I go to http://localhost  and I see the apache default page.  All good.
My problem is, I go to http://localhost/test.php and I get a 404.

Am I having a senior moment?

Comment: Then most probably either you have not connected Apache and PHP or `/var/www` is not your DocumentRoot

Comment: 404 means page not found on server. Are you using proper webroot directory?

Comment: 404 error means your `ServerRoot` location is different. You can check it in  apche's httpd.conf file.

Comment: search the filesystem for httpd.conf & if there's more than 1, figure out which one is being used & check DocumentRoot in there. On OSX there's a built-in Apache, so if you install one you end up with 2 Apaches & 2 httpd.conf files. Something similar may have happened here (don't know, I don't use Debian)

Comment: Default location for most distros is /var/www/html not /var/www.

Comment: Thanks Devon,  this is what the actual problem was.  You're the man.

Answer (score 1):

According to [commanigy.com blog page](http://www.commanigy.com/blog/2011/06/08/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location) first run command:

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

The result of this command will be few lines something like this:

```
root      4053     1  0 06:26 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Copy given path and run following command:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -V
```

In the result find the line:

```
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

If you have like me - relative path without root element `/` on the beginning locate the line:

```
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
```

and join this both values. In our example will be:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Now look into this file using vim editor and search for `DocumentRoot` setting. In my file it looks like:

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Now copy your `test.php` to the this folder and run it using web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the php file extension is not allowed on your server setup.

Try something like this may help:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is worth noting, but if this was his only problem, he'd be seeing a page that contained his PHP, rather than getting a 404

Comment: You don't want text/html for php files.

Comment: if the server was setup to deny all access to file that where not html files then a 404 error would occur. https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4557229.htm

Comment: That'd be a very unusual/rare config, and even more unlikely that it'd generate a 404.  Not answer worthy unless something else points to it.